# Spinner's entries are too long

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner, ormlite

I have a spinner in my android application with more than 100 options... Is there a way for the user to go to one letter faster than scrolling the spinner down? Like in a website select you enter one letter with the keyboard ("p" for example) and you go straight to options startin with letter "p"...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a AutoCompleteTextView. Check [this](http://practicaldroid.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/spinner-vs-autocompletetextview.html) sample code.

Comment: An autoCompleteTextView sounds like the way to go.